# What is the equivalence of org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean in Spring 6?

Tags: spring, ehcache, java-17, tomcat10

I'm trying to migrate my project (jdk 17, tomcat 10.1.12, using xml file for configuration) from spring 5 to spring 6. But I get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.

Is there a package in spring 6 that replaces org.springframework.cache.ehcache? How can I use it?

my pom.xml:
[image]
[image]

I saw this documentation https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x but I didn't know what to do for real.

And there is something that I can't understand, every time I search for "EhCache for spring 6" they said that spring 6 match with ehcache 3.x but for my case I have ehcache 2.x like you can see in my pom, it's that normal?

Comment: [spring-context-support](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support) if you will add this one dependency it is going to help you.

Comment: From the description I would understand you should move to JCache *We did not replace org.springframework.cache.ehcache with an updated version, as using ehcache through the JCache API or its new native API is preferred.*

Comment: thank you for your help. I already have the spring-context-support dependency, i will move to ehcache 3 and use the JCache and see if that will work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Ehcache 2 is end of life and the maintanance ended in spetember 2023.

As it written in the [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x) you should update to ehcache 3 and use the JCache Api.

So the replacement of EhCacheManagerFactoryBean would be

```
org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheManagerFactoryBean
```