# EhCacheManager issue in springboot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, version, ehcache

I am getting the following error

"Cannot resolve symbol 'EhCacheManagerFactoryBean'

After updating springboot version from 2.7 to 3.2..

Please suggest me the solution for the same

Added web,starter cache, cache api, ehcache dependency

@EnableCaching

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77141391/what-is-the-equivalence-of-org-springframework-cache-ehcache-ehcachemanagerfacto) answer your question?